# Related to elsevier

Tags: pdftex

Hi I can run my code on overleaf and texworks but when I submit it to the Elsevier journal I can't build the pdf file and have the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)
(LaTeX) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX) is dated 2022-10-26, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX) at least 2022-12-17. For immediate help type H
.
...
l.77 \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}
}
```

I am not an expert at using Latex. Could anyone please help? would be much appreciated.

Comment: check which of your packages is demanding 2022-12-17 version (or show more of the log here in a code block) and use an older package. Possibly it is an incorrect update of latex on elsevier's server and you need to report it to them to fix. Hard to say without full log

Comment: actually looking again at the message I think this is an error on elsevier's installation, they need to rebuild the format

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem regarding the Editorial Manager for Elsevier, specifically for the elsarticle.cls file. I was able to solve this problem with the following steps:

1. Delete the following Lines of Code from the elsarticle.cls:

> ```
> \IfFileExists{expl3.sty}{%   
>  \global\useexplthreefunctionstrue%
>  \RequirePackage{expl3}}{}
> ```

2. include modified elsarticle.cls as a manuscript item in the submission